# Whether to run integrity check before or after backups (Ola H FAQ)?

Tags: sql-server, backup, ola-hallengren, dbcc-checkdb

Going through Ola H FAQ's, https://ola.hallengren.com/frequently-asked-questions.html, I see that

> I also recommend that you perform the full backup after the integrity
> check.

Isn't the opposite true? That is - running integrity check after the backup is better because then you'd know for sure whether that backup is corrupted or not.

Answer (score 4):

It really doesn't matter, either way, to be honest. If you run the backup first and then run the integrity check, you don't know if the backup is good - you know it ran. If you run the integrity check first it's the same answer. You know the database was fine but you don't know if the backup is good.

You can *assume* either way that both are good but there have been a handful of issues I've worked on where this was not the case. Generally, though, either way, so long as you're doing it, is good and the same.

If you want to be sure, take a backup, restore it to a different server, run an integrity check on it. Then you'll know you have a good backup and a good database.